# AngularJS Datatable Showing No Data Available in Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

Okay so I am new to AngularJS but not new to coding. For the most part I have understood everything with Angular but I am getting stuck on one thing for the past few days I have been pulling my hair out. Hopefully one of you can tell me what I am doing wrong.

I am using AngularJS and Jquery Datatables. The data loads from the controller just fine even shows it as a row however it is above the Jquery Box... inside the Jquery Box it tells me "No Data Available" it also says Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries even though 1 row should appear.

Here is what the HTML Looks like like for the table:

```
<table ng-if="ConductorTypes" class="table table-striped table-hover" datatable-setup id="ConductorTypes" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr data-ng-repeat="conductorType in ConductorTypes">
                        <td>
                            {{ conductorType.id }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ conductorType.name }}
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
</table>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
'use strict';
app.controller('ConductorTypesController', ['$scope', 'stagingService', function ($scope, stagingService) {

    $scope.ConductorTypes = [];

    stagingService.getConductorTypes().then(function (results) {

        $scope.ConductorTypes = results.data;

    }, function (error) {
        alert(error.data.message);
    });

}]);
```

Now I also setup the directive and that looks like this:

```
app.directive('datatableSetup', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E, A, C',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var table = element.dataTable({
                    "aoColumnDefs": [{
                        'bSortable': true,
                        'aTargets': [-1]
                    }],
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sPrevious": "Previous",
                            "sNext": "Next"
                        }
                    },
                    "iDisplayLength": 10,
                    "aLengthMenu": [
                      [5, 10, 25, 50, -1],
                      [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]
                    ],
                    "sDom": '<"dt-panelmenu testbutton"><"dt-panelmenu clearfix"Tfr>t<"dt-panelfooter clearfix"ip>',
                    "oTableTools": {
                        "sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
);
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is this not populating the Jquery Datatable. Any help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Your "element.dataTable" is most likely running before the controller populates it

Comment: You should use datatables directive. https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/. There's no need to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a timeout thanks to @Kevin F who gave me the idea to load it after it loads.

Comment: where to add the time out ?can you update the answer with a working code ?

Comment: @query   ` $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event) {
        if ($state.current.name == 'tables') {
          // delay
          $timeout(function () {
           
            $scope.getDataTable();
            
          }, 900);


        }
      });` Hope this helps